# Font-face is not working in Google Chrome & Firefox using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, fonts, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing problem with custom font-face using bootstrap3 folder, i have added new fonts in font folder at root level. but fonts are not working with Firefox & chrome browser.

I have read topic related to glyphicons & i am not willing to change files in any browser.

Without bootstrap all fonts are accessible in normal html page.

Any suggestion

Regards & Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Bootstrap import it's own font-family to use. There are several ways to overcome this problem:

Right way:
Compile your own CSS from the Bootstrap LESS files, and choosing your own font-style. You can do that by changing the LESS variable file and compile it, or on http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ by changing the font-family. Be sure to import the font properly.

Easy way:
Be sure to import and use your font styled CSS **after** importing the Bootstrap CSS.